# web2py Can't import run functions from imported module

Tags: python, web2py

I'm trying to import external modules into my controller code for a web2py application. The module I'm importing is located in myapp/modules and seems to import fine. However, it doesn't let me call any of the functions defined in there; gives the following error 
 **'module' object has no attribute 'testfunc'**

I'm importing like this:

```
import json_utils as u
```

And calling like this:

```
u.testfunc()
```

Am I missing something obvious here? I have tried stop/starting the server in case its not reloaded the file.

Cheers

EDIT: Here is the entire json_utils.py file:

```
def testfunc():
    return 3

def testfunc2():
    # some stuff
    return 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is web2py caching external modules. Stop/Starting the server is not enough, I need to kill the whole thing are reboot.

Comment: I had to reload my web application to make ir works. Quite odd, for me, but did worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that json_utils has no function called testfunc

Comment: But there is a function called that in the json_utils. Defined as: `def testfunc(): return 5` I've kept it simple because this is something that should just **work**.

Answer (score 0):

The module json_utils has no built-in function testfunc()

for example if I do

```
import random
u.nonfunction()
```

and then I run it I get 
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'nonfunction'`

but if I do a function that it has

```
import random
random = u.randrange(1,10)
print(random)
```

It works properly

Comment: It isn't a case of I was expecting to pull random functions out of thin air. The functions are there, just it wont let me call them.